# angularFire() is returning undefined when the controller is loaded the second time

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am a new to angularjs and am playing around with it with firebase. Am following the 
[angularFire tutorial](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire) for implicit sync.

My code for the controller is

```
trankeeloManagerApp.controller('StoresCtrl', [
    'NavService', '$scope', 'angularFire',
    function(NavService, $scope, angularFire) {
  NavService.updateActiveNav();

  var url = '[MY_URL]/users/test_user/stores';
  $scope.stores = angularFire(url, $scope, 'stores', []);
  $scope.store = {
    name: '',
    tin: '',
    description: ''
  };

  $scope.page = {
    show_list_loading : true,
    show_list_table : false,
    show_list : true,
    show_add_item : false,
    show_add_button : false,
  };

  $scope.stores.then(function(stores) {
    $scope.hideList();
    console.log(stores);

    $('#datatables').dataTable( {
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        },
        "aaData" : $scope.stores,
        "aoColumns": [
          { "sTitle": "Name",   "mData": "name", "mDataProp" : "name" },
          { "sTitle": "TIN",  "mData": "tin", "mDataProp" : "tin" },
          { "sTitle": "Description", "mData": "description", "mDataProp" : "description" }
        ]
    });
    $scope.page.show_add_button = true;
    $scope.addStore = function(){
      $scope.showList();
      $scope.stores.push($scope.store);
      addStoreInDatatable($scope.store);
      $scope.store = {
        name: '',
        tin: '',
        description: ''
      };
    };

    $scope.removeStore = function (store) {
      $scope.stores.splice($scope.stores.indexOf(store), 1);
    };

    //TODO implement edit
  });

  $scope.showAddStore = function(){
    $scope.page.show_add_item = true;
    $scope.page.show_list = false;
  }

  $scope.cancelAddStore = function(){
    $scope.hideList();
  }

  $scope.showList = function(){
    $scope.page.show_add_item = false;
    $scope.page.show_list = true;
  };

  $scope.hideList = function(){
    $scope.page.show_list_loading = false;
    $scope.page.show_list_table = true;
  };

  function addStoreInDatatable(store){
    $('#datatables').dataTable().fnAddData({
      "name" : store.name,
      "tin" : store.tin,
      "description" : store.description 
    });
  };

  $scope.showList();

}]);
```

Everything works well the first load, but when I go to another controller and go back. I get this error.

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined

Comment: I tried debugging the code and it pointed to this method `_safeApply`.  
When `fn();` is called it is undefined, I am to new js so this is as far as I can go for now. I'll try to look at this more later when I wake up

Comment: Good catch, the issue is that the value handler is called synchronously if the value is cached locally. Thomas has correctly identified the problem, I'll merge the fix soon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experiencing the same behavior I think there <strike>is currently</strike> was a [bug](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/pull/8) in `angularFire.js`:

If the requested value is already cached locally, then `angularFire()` does return `undefined` instead of a (resolved) promise.

*Update:* The bug is now [fixed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/commit/6873941f14996d0b2ef509a308320f3bf89485e9).

Regarding your issue with subsequent calls to `$scope.stores.push`: I suggest to differentiate between the bound value (named in the 3rd arg to angularFire()) and the promise of the binding (as returned by angularFire()):

```
$scope.promise = angularFire(url, $scope, 'stores', []);
$scope.promise.then (function () {
    $scope.stores = { foo: 'bar', ... };
});
```

Comment: this fixed the issue, but when I add another entry, its throwing an error with a non existing method `.push`

Comment: its fixed! :) I had to revert my code back to implicit sync to check, changed to explicit to make everything work before I tested this. Thanks a lot! :) I am new to this stuff and its taking quite awhile for me to learn. Cheers!